# Enabling TCP/IP using visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016, tcp

I created a SQL Server 2016 database using MS Visual Studio 2017. I need to enable TCP/IP so I can connect to my database but I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried using SQL Server Configuration Manager but it can't find the database to begin with, let alone change one of its settings.

I can see the database in Visual Studio, but I can't find an option to enable TCP/IP.

Comment: What does your **connection string** (or SQL Server's server/instance name) look like? Is it something like `(localdb)\......` - then stop wasting your time - the "Local DB" is **only** for local connections - you **cannot** enable TCP/IP and remote access to it .

Comment: yeah, it's on localdb, I'll stop trying to enable TCP/IP.  What do I need to do to get a javascript app running on my computer to talk with the database running on localdb?